# Split string by second comma, then by third comma

Tags: c#, split

I have a string which looks like this:

> Less than $5,000, $5,000-$9,999, $10,000-$14,999, $45,000-$49,999, $50,000-$54,999

And what I would like to have is:

> Less than $5,000 or $5,000-$9,999 or $10,000-$14,999 or $45,000-$49,999 or $50,000-$54,999

What I tried is:

```
items[1].Split(new char[1] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(e => new AnswerModel { Name = e }).ToList()
```

Name should be "Less than $5,000" then "$5,000-$9,999" and so on.

But it splits by every comma, I would need to split it first by the second and then by the third.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: what you seem to want to do is replace ", $" with " or $"

Comment: I think `items[1].Split(new string[] { ", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` will work

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: It doesn't work because the string has no space ""Less than $5,000,$5,000-$9,999,$10,000-$14,999,$45,000-$49,999,$50,000-$54,999", I'm sorry for writing it wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string looks exactly as you pasted here, and it will always have such pattern, then you can split on a string of two characters:

```
items[1].Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Update:**

But if your string is without spaces, then you should replace first with some unique character like `|`, and then split over that new character:

```
items[1].Replace(",$", "|$").Split(new char[1] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Also you can replace it with `or $` and the string would be already in desired format, and there would be no need to split and join again.

This should do the trick.

Comment: No, my bad, unfortunately it's like this "Less than $5,000,$5,000-$9,999,$10,000-$14,999,$45,000-$49,999,$50,000-$54,999"

Comment: But if I woudn't have the "$", let's say "NULL VALUE,25,000-30,000,31,000-32,000,33,000-50,000" ?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can split by `", "`

```
string s = "Less than $5,000, $5,000-$9,999, $10,000-$14,999, $45,000-$49,999, $50,000-$54,999";
string result = string.Join(" or ", s.Split(new []{", "},StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Returns your desired result:

> Less than $5,000 or $5,000-$9,999 or $10,000-$14,999 or
>   $45,000-$49,999 or $50,000-$54,999